# Canopy - Permission Denied

Tags: python, permissions, file-permissions, enthought, canopy

I recently installed Enthought Canopy for an intro class to Python. It was working fine until the other day when a friend messed with some settings on my computer. Now when I try to run Canopy I am given the following message:

Permission denied while creating:
C:\Users\Emmeline\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy\running_procs.pkl
Please change permissions and restart Canopy.

My computer runs Windows 7 on which I have complete Administrator rights. I have attempted to reinstall Canopy several times, once following the instructions on [this Enthought support site](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy) but nothing has worked.

Comment: have you checked the permissions for `C:\Users\Emmeline\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy`?

Answer (score 0):

If your previous installation of Canopy was corrupted, a half-running version of it may have been blocking your re-installation.

You may need to restart your computer both before and after deleting the directories described in [[the uninstall procedure]](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy), in order to ensure that files from your previous installation are really gone. The procedure has now been expanded to explicitly suggest this.

Also, after you do step 5 of the procedure, be sure that `C:\Users\Emmeline\AppData\Roaming\Enthought\Canopy` is really deleted.

Note that AppData is a hidden folder, so just because you can't find AppData doesn't mean you don't need to delete these folders. This is described in the procedure.